# Change URLs depending on alias

Tags: urls

I have two domain names: themaindomain.com and thealias.com.
Wordpress is located under themaindomain.com.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the urls to posts and pages when there is a request from thealias.com
To make clear:
When there is a request from themaindomain.com, the server returns a page with some links like themaindomain.com/post1, themaindomain.com/page1.
When there is a request from thealias.com, the server should return a page with some other links like thealias.com/post1, thealias.com/page1.
So the two domains point to the same blog, but depending on the request url it changes the links.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the `WP_HOME` directive in your [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29).  Just set it dynamically based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` like the example in the codex.

```
<?php
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

You might also want to define `WP_SITEURL` in the same way.  I do something like the above for the wp-content url on one of my sites:

```
<?php
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/content');
```

All that said, the SEO in me is screaming that this is a terrible idea -- duplicate content and such. Much better to have a single site and redirect the alias to the canonical site.

Comment: About that SEO, you're right,  I guess. I haven't thought that much about it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Thank you for this! I found it today when I was searching for a way to change the URL for aliases in WordPress itself instead of htaccess. But I added `s` to get `https://` instead, since your answer was in 2012 and now https is more common. Anyway, **you mentioned it was bad in terms of SEO, could you please elaborate on that?** Is it bad for all websites or just those that have specific marketing needs?

Comment: You generally want to have exactly one URL at which content lives or you'll get penalized for duplicate content. Stuff like `rel="conical"` links can help with this.